# Scroll through text file and know line numbers

Tags: vba, excel, csv, text, file-io

Looking for the best way to proceed.

This code can grab the files in a directory. Then it opens each file and displays each line of the file, then loops to the next file.

As it scrolls through the lines, build a string concatenating lines/partial lines with a comma delimiter, then write this string to a csv file row.

If a line is a specific number, I want to grab that line. As example, I know I want to grab lines 1, 2, 2nd from last, etc. For other lines, if the line has certain content, parse that line for the data I want. i.e. "-2014-", then grab "2014-" and the next 5 characters (date)

```
GetFiles()

Function GetFiles
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "C:\hgis\a"
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
    Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
    mfn = objStartFolder +"\"+ objFile.Name
    msgbox CountLines(mfn) 
    Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(mfn,1)
    Dim strLine, TotStr
    TotStr = "CellA"
    do while not objFileToRead.AtEndOfStream
         strLine = objFileToRead.ReadLine()
         msgbox strline
         'Build string of multiple lines and parts of lines
         'TotStr = TotStr +","+ strline 
         'Parse lines for specific data - i.e. "-2014-" to get date/time stamp
         'Capture data and store to csv file for Excel analysis
    loop
    objFileToRead.Close
    Set objFileToRead = Nothing
Next
End Function


Function CountLines(mFile)
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set theFile = fso.OpenTextFile(mFile, 8, True) 
CountLines = theFile.Line
Set oFso = Nothing
End Function
```

Or maybe read all the lines into an array, then build the string by adding the elements. Then search array elements for content and parse the data out of them and add to the string.

Comment: I was hoping to get expert ideas on how best to scroll through a text file. While I've been able to put this code together, I'm new to vbscript and don't know all the function calls. Much less the best way of doing it. I'm collecting data via a DOS bat file that logs to a text file. I want to parse the lines one at a time and pull the desired data. In pulling the data, build a comma delimited string so I can save it to a csv file. That's one reason I suggested reading all the lines into an array. That does make sense, then I can loop through    each line and grab the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For grabbing certain lines, put the lines you want in an array:

```
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim iFileLines As Integer
iFileLines = CountLines(mfn)
arr = Array(1, 2, iFileLines - 1) ' first, second and 2nd last
```

Add a line count to

```
...
Dim iLine As Integer
iLine = 0
Do While Not objFileToRead.AtEndOfStream
    iLine = iLine + 1
...
```

And then check if the line number is in the array:

```
If IsError(WorksheetFunction.Match(iLine, arr, False)) Then
    ' It isn't in the array, ignore it
Else:
    ' It is in the array, grab it
End If
```

Picking out the date and assigning to a variable would look like:

```
i = InStr(strLine, "-2014-")
If i > 0 Then
    strDate = Mid(strLine, i + 1, 10)
    MsgBox strDate
End If
```

Anything further I'd need more detail about what you want to do with the strings as far as parsing etc.

**EDIT**
Apply your logic and build a string within the `Do While Not objFileToRead.AtEndOfStream` loop then save to a .csv

```
Do While Not objFileToRead.AtEndOfStream
    ' Check line for certain criteria, for example if you just want 
    ' the lines with a date:
    i = InStr(strLine, "-2014-")
    If i > 0 Then
        ' Build your string
        ' Save it to .csv
    End If
```

If you need help on how to build a string I suggest you ask a new question with examples of the original string and what you want to convert it to and the logic to be applied.

**EDIT TO SHOW ADDING TO ARRAY**

To add each line to an array you need to ReDim the array and then step through:

```
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim iFileLines As Integer
iFileLines = CountLines(mfn)
ReDim arr(0 to iFileLines - 1)

Dim iLine As Integer
iLine = 0

Do While Not objFileToRead.AtEndOfStream
    arr(iLine) = objFileToRead.ReadLine()
    iLine = iLine + 1
```

You can then step through the array:

```
Dim x as Integer
For x = 0 To UBound(arr) - 1
    strLine = arr(x)
    ' do what you need with the line
```

Comment: This looks very promising. It confirms my suspicion about the array. How would I change the line "arr = Array" to include all lines?

Comment: The `Do While Not objFileToRead.AtEndOfStream` loop will go through each line. I thought the purpose of the array was to pick out certain lines you wanted 'As example, I know I want to grab lines 1, 2, 2nd from last, etc'. As it loops through each line you can apply your selection criteria, build your string and then save it a .csv

Comment: Yes, this will work, but then if all the lines were in the array, I could loop through them in a different way then the AtEndofStream. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need to but I will edit the answer to show how to put it in an array.

Comment: When my script runs and hits this line..."If IsError(Application.Match(iLine, arr, False)) Then" it errors and says "Object required: Application". I've tried a number of ways using createobject for it, but I'm stuck.

Comment: @Carl-eieio, My apologies, change it to `WorksheetFunction`. I pulled the code from MS Access application, it worked when I tested it in Excel bu not sure if it is a reference thing or version difference etc that yours does not work. Try it with `WorksheetFunction` which is the Excel standard

Comment: code is coming along great. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127080/code-fails-on-application-match-call-object-required-message - I'm not using this code within Excel, not sure if that makes a difference. Thanks Simon.

Comment: WorksheetFunction balked and is looking for an object too. Maybe because I am running this script as a Windows file and not from within an application. i.e. Excel

Comment: Yes, it would still need an object. The solution was based on you having tagged the question as `Excel-VBA`, I'm not sure how you would dim Excel as an object when scripting as a windows file

Comment: Someone else tagged that on my behalf I guess, wasn't me. Unfortunately, they failed to inject any response or suggestions to help resolve.